# web.go install error

Tags: go, goinstall

I am trying to install [web.go](http://github.com/hoisie/web.go) using goinstall github.com/hoisie/web.go, and I keep getting an error about the path.

```
goinstall: github.com/hoisie/web.go: git: no such file or directory
```

goinstall is working for sure because when I type in just goinstall I get the options list for it. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Metropolis

Comment: Put your update into separate question.

Comment: Done. Sorry Sebastian, you are correct I should have put the second question into a new area. Thanks for the tip! New location = http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893772/import-web-go-error-after-using-goinstall

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install git (http://git-scm.com) in order to fetch packages from a git repository.

Cheers,
Fabian

Comment: Ah....so git HAS to be installed? I am a Mercurial user and I was trying to avoid Git :p

Answer (score 1):

If you install web.go through goinstall, you need to do:

```
import "github.com/hoisie/web.go"
```

Comment: Thanks marketer that worked....That path is kind of messy, can I just move the files in there to a better location? Or will that cause goinstall to not know where it is when I update it?

Comment: Can this answer be moved to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893772/import-web-go-error-after-using-goinstall