# Import web.go error after using goinstall

Tags: go, goinstall

With [halfdans advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892352/web-go-install-error), I was successfully able to use goinstall github.com/hoisie/web.go without any errors after installing git first. However, now when I try to compile the sample code given, go is not finding the web package. I get the error,

```
main.go:4: can't find import: web
```

On this code

```
package main

import (
    "web"
)

func hello(val string) string { return "hello " + val }

func main() {
    web.Get("/(.*)", hello)
    web.Run("0.0.0.0:9999")
}
```

Is there something special I need to do in order for it to recognize the package? I found the package source at $GOROOT/src/pkg/github.com/hoisie/web.go/web. I tried github.com/hoisie/web.go/web as the import and it still did not like that.

Comment: Looks like this has been solved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892352/web-go-install-error/2893055#2893055

Comment: That was my original question I moved it here to split up the 2 questions I had. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you install web.go through goinstall, you need to do:

```
import "github.com/hoisie/web.go"
```

Goinstall is still an experimental system. It would be nice if you didn't have to include the full path.

Comment: Is there no way to alter this? Can I just move the files from github.com/hoisie/web.go to web/? Or would goinstall lose track of it if I do that?

Comment: You can just make a symbolic link using something like: `ln -s $GOROOT/src/pkg/github.com/hoisie/web.go ~/.node_libraries/`

Comment: Good idea Brian! I never think to make symbolic links when I know they make things much easier.

Comment: So is there no other way without messing things up then?

Comment: You can also go into $GOROOT/src/pkg/github.com/hoisie/web.go, and run a 'make install'. This will just install to the package 'web'

Comment: Sweet that worked! Thanks Hoisie......Before when I could not get goinstall working, I tried cloning the package with git, and running the make install on it, but I kept getting an error. Do you know why that would be?

Answer (score 2):

```
import web "github.com/hoisie/web.go"
```